# Adding a range of entries to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Right now I am doing like this in order to put some stuff in my database.

```
public void AddMonsters()
    {
        Monster NewMonster = new Monster();

        NewMonster.Level = 1;
        ....
        NewMonster.Strength = 10;
        db.Monsters.Add(NewMonster);
        db.SaveChanges();

        NewMonster.Level = 3;
        .....
        NewMonster.Strength = 197;
        db.Monsters.Add(NewMonster);
        db.SaveChanges();

        NewMonster.Level= 30;
        ....
        NewMonster.Strength = 275;
        db.Monsters.Add(NewMonster);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

I have to `SaveChanges` for every one.

But I know there's an `AddRange` function in the database, but I didn't get it to work.

How can I easily add multiple entries at once?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing the same variable `NewMonster`. If you create a new object instance for each monsters, you will be able to call `db.SaveChanges()` at the end only.

you could create a list of monsters, then use `AddRange()`.

```
var monsters = new List<Monster>() {
    new Monster { Level = 1, Strength = 10 },
    new Monster { Level = 10, Strength = 105 },
};

db.Monsters.AddRange(monsters);
db.SaveChanges();
```

To clarify, in your code snippet above Entity Framework is tracking exactly one instance of `Monster`--so you would have no way of using AddRange or not having to repeatedly call .SaveChanges().  You are literally taking the same object, changing the variables and then doing .Add and .SaveChanges.

Creating a list as specified is probably the cleanest solution to your problem--though you could create any collection of `Monster` and then add them all at once, using .AddRange just like you expected.